# Shell like application using sbt console

Tags: scala, sbt

I would like to deploy some scala code, to be used very similar to sbt console
(command line interface, history, etc)
and would like to

- customize it
- and made it simple to deploy.

Can sbt console be used with these changes:

- Removed startup info messages
- Removed scala welcome message
- Customized command prompt instead of "scala>" to be "myApp>"
- No access to local nor global ivy/maven repositories (all jars
  available, including sbt jars and dependencies)

Anybody passed this path ?

I have tried 
[Using sbt to build command line application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132133/using-sbt-to-build-command-line-application)
but with no much progress so far
(I guessed it was intented to very similar situation)

Are there ready made plugin available ? 
Any other tool related or unrelated to sbt ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actully, no need for sbt. To have it tweaked, scala code should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

For the sbt "Customized command prompt" part, you have a good example with "[**sbt: Customize the Shell prompt in sbt**](http://www.whiteboardcoder.com/2016/03/sbt-customize-shell-prompt-in-sbt.html)" from [Patrick Bailey (`patmandenver`)](https://gist.github.com/patmandenver).

> create the `~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt` file:

```
vi ~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt
```

> And place the following in it.

```scala
shellPrompt := { state =>
  def textColor(color: Int)      = { s"\033[38;5;${color}m" }
  def backgroundColor(color:Int) = { s"\033[48;5;${color}m" }
  def reset                      = { s"\033[0m" }

  def formatText(str: String)(txtColor: Int, backColor: Int) = {
    s"${textColor(txtColor)}${backgroundColor(backColor)}${str}${reset}"
  }
  val red    = 1
  val green  = 2
  val yellow = 11
  val white  = 15
  val black  = 16
  val orange = 166

  formatText(s"[${name.value}]")(white, orange) +
   "\n " +
   formatText("\u276f")(green, black) +
   formatText("\u276f")(yellow, black) +
   formatText("\u276f ")(red, black)
}
```

> Run reload in sbt and….

[image: https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-tPdrR9q-gls/Vuf61H7koFI/AAAAAAAAK7s/aqIkdp49DRk_im6F4RZgPj6qElP-ePWUw/s640/customize_shell_prompt_027.png]

That can be amended/enhanced/completed to add other information you would need in your case.